# how to convert a set of hex strings to byte array

Tags: c++

I have an input of char `*str = "13 00 0A 1B CA 00";`

I need an output as `BYTE bytes[] = { 0x13, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x1B, 0xCA, 0x00 };`

can somebody help with a solution?

Comment: `sscanf` might work, but he may not know the exact number of bytes in the string, so he needs a more dynamic approach.

Comment: sscanf is not safe, it causes 'buffer overrun'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873402/is-sscanf-considered-safe-to-use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to parse out each of the two characters and then convert them into `BYTE`. This isn't fairly difficult to do.

```
std::stringstream converter;
std::istringstream ss( "13 00 0A 1B CA 00" );
std::vector<BYTE> bytes;

std::string word;
while( ss >> word )
{
    BYTE temp;
    converter << std::hex << word;
    converter >> temp;
    bytes.push_back( temp );
}
```

Comment: Which c++ compiler are you using that has a function named hex_string_to_int in the standard library?

Comment: I'm sorry that is not exactly what I ment, I'm going to change that.

Comment: I didn't quite understand this, can you explain in more detail please>

Comment: my strings are "xx xx xx xx" format, will strstream work with the spaces?

Comment: typedef unsigned short BYTE;

Comment: why extra stream `converter`  is used? It can be done directly on the `ss` stream!

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that the input format is actually 3 chars for each hex BYTE. I used `sscanf` for simplicity, `streams` are obviously also an option.

```
    std::vector<BYTE> bytes;
    char *str = "13 00 0A 1B CA 00";
    std::string input(str);

    size_t count = input.size()/3;
    for (size_t i=0; i < count; i++)
    {           
        std::string numStr = input.substr(i*3, input.find(" "));

        int num=0;
        sscanf(numStr.c_str(), "%x", &num);
        bytes.push_back((BYTE)num);
    }

    // You can access the output as a contiguous array at &bytes[0]
    // or just add the bytes into a pre-allocated buffer you don't want vector
```

Comment: Actually `count` of bytes is `(input.size() + 1)/3`. Your code will miss last byte in input string.