# Conditional Jump or move depends on unitialised value

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

So, valgrind gave me that error and I ran it with --track-origins=yes and found the line where the error is, but I don't understand what the error is or how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Date{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
} Date;

typedef struct Data{
    Date date;
    float temp;
    float uncertainty;
    char country[100];
} Data;

int main(){
    FILE* f = fopen("tempcountries_short.csv", "r");
    char* line = NULL;
    int capacity = 0;
    int countries_capacity = 0;
    int line_ix = 0;
    char c;
    Data* country = NULL;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != '\n'){ 
        if (line_ix + 1 > capacity){
            if (capacity == 0)                    
                capacity = 10;
            else
                capacity = capacity * 2;
            line = realloc(line, capacity); 
        }
        line[line_ix] = c;
        line_ix++;
    }
    if (countries_capacity == 0)
        countries_capacity = 10;
    else
        countries_capacity = countries_capacity * 2;
    country = realloc(country, countries_capacity);
    printf("%i\n",sscanf(line, "%i - %i - %i, %f , %f , %s", 
           &country->date.year, &country->date.month,
           &country->date.day, &country->temp, &country->uncertainty,
           country->country));
}
```

This is the output from Valgrind, with options --leak-check=full and --track-origins=yes: https://pastebin.com/EyqDGBmQ As you can see there are many other errors, and I don't understand what causes them either.

The program is reading lines from a file with data about many countries temperatures, I just took the part of the code for a single country to replicate the error, but country is supposed to be an array of many Data structs. Here's an example line from the file I'm reading:

1972-03-01,4.787,0.342,Slovakia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
country = realloc(country, countries_capacity);
```

You appear to be relying on `realloc(0, new_size)` to behave as `malloc(new_size)`.  That's fine, but then you must make sure that the pointer variable passed to `realloc` really is null.  No code before this point initializes the `country` variable, and in its declaration ...

```
Data* country;
```

... there's no initializer.  Change this to

```
Data *country = 0;
```

and that part of the problem should go away.

Often, when you get a whole string of errors from `valgrind`, only the first one is meaningful, so see if that fixes all of your problems.

---

EDIT: With the version of the program with the above corrected, fed the sample line of input shown, I do not get any complaints about uninitialized values inside `realloc`, but I do still get a complaint about uninitialized values inside `sscanf`:

```
==28542== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28542==    at 0x4C340E6: rawmemchr (vg_replace_strmem.c:1409)
==28542==    by 0x4EB6291: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:41)
==28542==    by 0x4EA476C: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:41)
==28542==    by 0x4EA46D3: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:31)
==28542==    by 0x108886: main (in /tmp/a.out)
```

and a complaint about invalid writes:

```
==28542== Invalid write of size 4
==28542==    at 0x4E98FFB: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1898)
==28542==    by 0x4EA4781: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:43)
==28542==    by 0x4EA46D3: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:31)
==28542==    by 0x108886: main (in /tmp/a.out)
==28542==  Address 0x51f41a8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 10 alloc'd
==28542==    at 0x4C2CABF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==28542==    by 0x4C2EE04: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==28542==    by 0x10883C: main (in /tmp/a.out)
```

These are both caused by real bugs: the first is because the `line` array is never made into a proper C-string (by adding a nul terminator), the second is because the *size* passed to `realloc` is wrong.  You need

```
line[line_ix] = '\0';
```

immediately after the `while` loop, and

```
country = realloc(country, countries_capacity * sizeof(Data));
```

instead of the `realloc` call you have now.

---

With those changes, I get no valgrind complaints. You do still have the problem that you're using `sscanf`, which is [always a bad idea](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), but valgrind can't help you with that.

Comment: Why not use bzero instead of = NULL or = 0 ? It is exactly the same ?

Comment: Actually that was a mistake I made when I copied the code to limit the mistake, in the original I had the initialization to NULL. I just changed it and ran Valgrind again, it didn't solve anything. Also, the link you gave says that scanf is a bad idea, not sscanf.

Comment: Re the remaining valgrind complaints see edits.  Re (s)scanf, all of the flaws described for scanf at the page in the link apply _equally_ to sscanf (yes, I know that the author of that page doesn't see it that way).

Comment: @AntoninGavrel `bzero` is deprecated and one should use `memset` in its place.  And even then, the point is to set a range of bytes; if just setting one var, there isn't much reason to use such a sledgehammer.

Comment: @zwol Can you explain why you think so about sscanf, perhaps in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873402/is-sscanf-considered-safe-to-use? I'm genuinely curious. By the way, you are right, now everything runs correctly, so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
country = realloc(country, countries_capacity);
```

`country` has not been initialized, it contains an indeterminate value.

Just initialize `country` to `NULL` upon declaration like this:

```
Data* country = NULL;
```

Comment: As I said in the other comment, that doesn't actually change anything, and in the original code I had the initialization to NULL. I've updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The last character of line must be set to \0, to be a proper null terminated string.