# If I have a character array in C++, how does this work?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a **char array** of size 5
and:

```
char array[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{ 
    scanf>>array[i];
}
```

And I as a user of this program provide "hello" as an input. Where is the \0 stored as character arrays are null terminating in C++ right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `where is the \0 stored` -- It isn't.  You need a six character array to store `hello\0`, but your array is only 5 characters in size.

Comment: BTW, the `operator>>` can't be used correctly with with `scanf`, unless `scanf` is derived from `std::istream` or is a class that has `operator>>` defined.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your are mixing concepts.

- `cin>>`is C++ syntax, not C (for C you have to use [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) -or [sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873453/7520531) -, [`fgets`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html), etc)
- A proper formatted string in C ends with null `\0`, but it does not mean that any array of type `char` has to end with `\0`.
- The world "hello" will be stored as:

  ```
  char array[0] = 'h';
  char array[1] = 'e';
  char array[2] = 'l';
  char array[3] = 'l';
  char array[4] = 'o';
  char array[5] = '\0';
  ```

So you will need an array of size=6, being the extra char the `null` character.

Comment: so a character array is always not null terminating then? It's not the case here right?

Comment: An array of type char can (or cannot) end with the null character. A string must end with the null character.

Comment: I couldn't get your point but a character array is a string, right?

Comment: Yes, strings are array of characters terminated by the null character.

Comment: In C so every character array is a string as there is no string datatype. And If I dynamically allocate a array to get char from user then I won't have to worry about the  "\0" right? as there will be no space just like in my question.

Comment: A C-style string is always an array of characters terminated by a null, even if read from the user. But an array of characters is not required to be treated as a C-style string (ie, an array of bytes instead), so it does not require a null terminator (but then you have to keep track of how many valid `char`s are in the array).  And a C++-style string (`std::string`) does not require a null terminator, either.